# Clicking on a span object in phantomjs

Tags: html, css, phantomjs

i want to click on a element on a website. The website contains a list and every element is expandable. The element i want to click on causes an entry of the list to expand, so its something like a "show detailed info" button.

First, here is the html code where the button is defined:

```
<td>
       <span id="span_details62_0">
         <a href="#" onclick="setBusy(&#x27;running-indication&#x27;);
                render_event_cluster(&#x27;104,105&#x27;, 620);
                toggle_fe(&#x27;dtlsRow620&#x27;);
                change(&#x27;span_details62_0&#x27;, &#x27;show&#x27;);
                Element.update(&#x27;running-indication&#x27;,&#x27;&#x27;);; return false;"><img alt="show | hide" border="0" height="10" src="/images/layout/general/clear.gif?1408570117" title="Show/hide details" width="10" /></a>
       </span>
    </td>
```

what i am trying to do is this:

```
function(){

    page.evaluate(function(){

var a = document.getElementById("span_details62_0");
console.log('1 '+ a);
var e = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
console.log('2 '+ e);
e.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
console.log('3 '+ e.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null));
a.dispatchEvent(e);
console.log('4 '+ a.dispatchEvent(e));
waitforload = true;
});
},
```

The console output is this:

```
1 [object HTMLElement]
2 [object MouseEvent]
3 undefined
4 true
```

in the next step i save the page as html file and when i view it, the list is not expanded.
Does anyone see the problem?

Comment: Is it expanded when you take a screenshot? There are ways to show different parts of a page without changing the DOM (e.g. with the anchor).

Comment: @ArtjomB. both. The sourcecode doesnt change when i expand the list.

Comment: Does the span even have a click handler or did you want to trigger the click handler on the `<a>` element?

Comment: @ArtjomB. I don't think there is a click handler. If I use click without the definition in the 2nd code block it doesn't work. What i want is to make the website think that i have clicked on the button. The final goal is to view the expanded list. Do you need more parts of the html source code?

Comment: It seems to me that you're not clicking on the correct element. Try `var a = document.querySelector("#span_details62_0 > a");`

Comment: @ArtjomB. Tried, did not work. The 4 outputs of my console.log commands from above are now : 1 https://10.84.163.146/analysis/analyses#
2 [object MouseEvent]
3 undefined
4 false

Comment: "4 false" at least means that the click was triggered.